# Laravel get data with belongsto column

Tags: laravel, belongs-to

plans table columns
id, name, type

clients table columns
id, name, plan_id

```
// for client

function plan(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Plan::class, 'plan_id', 'id');
}
```

I input plan_id to Clients table

I want to get those clients data from clients table if plan type ='PP'

```
$clientData = Client::with(['plan' => function ($clientData) {
    $clientData->where('type', 'PP');
})->get();
```

I tried this but I got all data from clients table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->with()` doesn't constrain the data from the initial query, it just eager loads it. You need to use `->whereHas()` for that:

```
$clientData = Client::with(["plan"])
->whereHas("plan", function ($query) {
    $query->where("type", "=", "PP");
})->get();
```

This will only return `Client` records that have a `Plan` with a type of `PP`.

Comment: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
I got this error.

Comment: Woops, sorry. `->whereHas()` doesn't expect an array; fixed.

Comment: So How can get?

Comment: @ASMSaief the closure needs to be the 2nd arg to whereHas

Comment: Thank TimLewis And Devon